# Using getFragmentManager() in BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, fragment, expandablelistview, android-alertdialog, baseadapter

I am creating an custom expandable list. In the header i have added an ImageButton. I want to show an AlertDialog when The Image Button is clicked. for this I have made another class AlerttoB that extends DialogFragment. Everything is working fine but to show the Alert Dialog i used myAlert.show(getFragmentManager(), "My Alert"); which gives an error: The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

The code is given below, please someone tell how to show the alert dialog in this scenerio or any wayaround for getfragmentManager() over here. Thanks.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;


public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}



@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);


    ImageButton buttonAdd = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAdd);
    buttonAdd.setFocusable(false);
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            AlerttoB myAlert = new AlerttoB();
            myAlert.show(getFragmentManager(), "My Alert");






        }  
    });  

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

AlertoB class code:

```
public class SmsBlackListAlertInput extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blocksendersms, null);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Negative Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});

builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.add, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Positive Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});

Dialog dialog = builder.create();
return dialog;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

You're already storing the context in your constructor, so just do `_context.getFragmentManager()` instead.

Comment: _context.getFragmentManager() gives The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Context

Comment: Try `((Activity) _context).getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Now its giving this error
The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)
whats the reason?

Comment: Ah, you might need the support fragment manager instead. Try `((Activity) _context).getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Nah its not working either..
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Activity
do you know of anyother way?

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty much out of ideas.. in your Activity code, maybe try changing `extends Activity` to `extends FragmentActivity`, and use `((Activity) _context).getFragmentManager()`?

Comment: which activity?  one thing more to add the log statement works inside the imagebutton onclickview. and DialogFragment is also a fragment so getfragmentManager should have worked

Comment: Yeah, it *should* have worked, that's the confusing part. Your second error message makes me think it's a name conflict somewhere (i.e. it's pulling `FragmentManager` from the wrong package), but if that isn't it then I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

OK

this was problem too!, So i try this and it work for me :

1- at first change yor declaration to this form :

```
    private FragmentManager FmBase;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData , FragmentManager FmMain) 
    {
       this._context = context;
       this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
       this._listDataChild = listChildData;

       this.FmBase= FmMain;
    }
```

and in your ImageButton onclick event use this

```
    {
       myAlert.show(FtBase, "My Alert");
    }
```

2- for pass getFragmentManager() try this in making adapter (For Exapmle) :

```
    ExpandableList_Adapter listAdapter = new ExpandableList_Adapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild,getFragmentManager());
```